# Viewing command history in Google Cloud shell

Tags: shell, google-cloud-platform, command-history

I am trying to view some commands I used several months ago for a course project. I used the history command but it only showed very recent lines. Is there a way to view older command history? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your list of executed commands is stored in [`.bash_history`](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-History-Facilities). You can find this file in the `home` folder of Cloud Shell.

Cloud Shell's home folder is deleted after 120 days of inactivity. So, if you're looking for commands that you used several months ago and your Cloud Shell was inactive for more than 120 days, chances are that your disk was deleted.

Also, by default, bash stores the last 500 executed commands history.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks so much. It has been over 120 days. Good to know this though!

Comment: Hi @natural_d if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.